# MYSQLI Connection refused when connecting to another docker container running MariaDB

Tags: php, docker, mysqli, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm starting to get my hands dirty with Docker and I'm trying to get my PHP application running in a docker container with nginx to connect to the database running in another container running MariaDB.

When I run the containers, I can connect without any problems to the database from my computer (using Sequel Pro) but when i try to connect to the database from the PHP application running in the nginx container I get the following mysqli error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in >/app/web/php/db-config.php on line 7
>   Failed to connect to the database, died with error:

The db-config.php where the error happens is as follows:

```
    define('DB_HOST', '0.0.0.0:3306');
    define('DB_NAME', 'Jumpooling');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Failed to connect to the database, died with error:');
```

All the docker-compose.yml file content is in [this](https://github.com/pgoodjohn/docker-php) repository.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are defining the port twice..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Chris!
I tried defining it only once both in the DB_HOST and in the mysqli_connect call and it did not workout, so I probably tried to put it in both just as a test end ended up copying and old version of the file.
Even by defining it only once it still does not work tho!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I managed to find the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378615/docker-mysql-cant-connect-to-container?rq=1) answer.

The problem was that the host was not to be defined as an IP address but with the link name that it is given in the `docker-compose.yml` file, that is `db`.

The final `db-config.php` is, thus:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'db');
define('DB_NAME', 'Jumpooling');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 3306) or die('Failed to connect to the database, died with error:');
```

Comment: Pick this answer as a best answer. Don't be shy

Comment: After long hours of trial and error, and endless Google searches along every new discovery on the way… I finally found the one answer to rule them all! :D

Answer (score 0):

Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the ports container/browser explicitly as -p 3306:3306:

```
docker run --name mysql-container -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql:latest
```